# Function that only works for the first two list from a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this list:

```
mylist = [
    [1890731350060, 'February 2016, March 2016, January 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183], 
    [1890922350110, 'May 2015, June 2015, April 2015', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183], 
    [1890731350060, 'February 2016, March 2016, January 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183]
]
```

and my desired output it this:

```
mylist = [
    [1890731350060, 'Ian 2016, Feb 2016, Mar 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183],
    [1890922350110, 'Iun 2016, Mai 2016, Apr 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183],
    [1890731350060, 'Ian 2016, Feb 2016, Mar 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183]
]
```

And for this I have this 2 functions:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re
def translateInRo(string, dyct):
    substrs = sorted(dyct, key=len, reverse=True)

    regexp = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, substrs)))

    return regexp.sub(lambda match: dyct[match.group(0)], string)

def orderDateslist(thislist):
    i=0
    for dates in thislist:
        sorted_list = []
        chgDates = dates[1].split(",")
        for test1 in chgDates:
            sorted_list.append(test1.strip())
        test = sorted(sorted_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%B %Y"))
        str1 = ', '.join(test)
        translate = translateInRo(
            str1, {"January": "Ian", "February": "Feb", "March": "Mar", "April": "Apr", "May": "Mai", "June": "Iun", "July": "Iul", "August": "Aug", "September": "Sept", "October": "Oct", "November": "Nov", "December": "Dec"})
        thislist[i][1] = translate
        i = + 1
    return thislist
```

And when I print:

```
print (orderDateslist(mylist))
[[1890731350060, 'Ian 2016, Feb 2016, Mar 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183], [1890922350110, 'Ian 2016, Feb 2016, Mar 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183], [1890731350060, 'February 2016, March 2016, January 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183]]
```

The last list won't be computed, the function that I have works only for the first 2 lists from a list of lists, the ones after will stay the same, I want this function to work for a big number of lists, what I have to change ? I'm using python 3. ANd also the last one is duplicating.

Comment: I don't understand the mapping of inputs to outputs. All English month names are to be mapped to Romanian names, I think. In the first instance, ` 'February 2016, March 2016, January 2016'` maps to `'Ian 2016, Feb 2016, Mar 2016'`; ie, the third date becomes the first. But in the second instance, `'May 2015, June 2015, April 2015'` becomes `'Iun 2016, Mai 2016, Apr 2016'`. Now the 3rd item remains in place, and the 1st and 2nd are swapped.

Comment: If you are interested in ordering dates by calendar, I believe `'Jun 2016, May 2016, Apr 2016'` in your expected code is incorrect.  It should be `'Apr 2015 May 2015 Jun 2015'`

Comment: Is there a reason why you are changing `J` to `I` and `y` to `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

To clarify the problem, from your expected code it appears you wish to replace the string of dates at index 1 of each sublist by:

1. sorting dates by time
2. abbreviating the months according to a translation dictionary

This can be done as follows:

```
# Given 
import datetime


mylist = [
    [1890731350060, 'February 2016, March 2016, January 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183], 
    [1890922350110, 'May 2015, June 2015, April 2015',         'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183], 
    [1890731350060, 'February 2016, March 2016, January 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183]
]

TRANSLATE = {
    "January": "Ian", "February": "Feb", "March": "Mar", "April": "Apr",
    "May": "Mai", "June": "Iun", "July": "Iul", "August": "Aug", 
    "September": "Sept", "October": "Oct", "November": "Nov", "December": "Dec"
}
```

**Code**

```
def transform_dates(iterable, translate=TRANSLATE):
    transformed_lists = []
    for i, sublst in enumerate(iterable):
        transformed_lists.append(sublst[:])

        # Clean dates string
        raw_dates = sublst[1]
        cleaned_dates = set(map(str.strip, raw_dates.split(",")))

        # Sort dates string
        months_yrs = sorted(cleaned_dates, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%B %Y"))
        months_yrs_split = [i.split() for i in months_yrs]

        # Abbreviate months
        abbrev_dates = [" ".join((translate[i[0]], i[1])) for i in months_yrs_split]
        transformed_lists[i][1] = ", ".join(abbrev_dates)
    return transformed_lists

transform_dates(mylist)
# [[1890731350060, 'Ian 2016, Feb 2016, Mar 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA',1183],
#  [1890922350110, 'Apr 2015, Mai 2015, Iun 2015', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA',1183],
#  [1890731350060, 'Ian 2016, Feb 2016, Mar 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA',1183]]
```

---

**Notes**

This function sorts by month and year.

```
lst = [1890731350060, 'February 2015, March 2013, January 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183], 
transform_dates(lst)
# [[1890731350060, 'Mar 2013, Feb 2015, Ian 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183]]
```

This function removes duplicate dates.

```
lst = [1890731350060, 'May 2016, June 2016, May 2016, July 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183], 
transform_dates(lst)
# [[1890731350060,'Mai 2016, Iun 2016, Iul 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183]]
```

**Details**

If you are new to Python, I add these details to help express what's happening.

The `transform_dates()` function accepts the list of lists called `mylist` as and argument.  Inside the function, we first make a new list called `transformed_lists` that we will later append items to. We now loop over `iterable` (equivalent to `mylist`) to get each `sublist` and track their index positions (`i`).

We add a copy of the `sublst` to `transform_dates` (hence the `[:]` as this keeps us from modifying the original items in `mylist`).  Then we start working on the first index that contains the string of dates.  We clean the string, first by splitting it into a list of month-year pairs, and then `strip` trailing and leading spaces, e.g. `['February 2016', 'March 2016', 'January 2016']`.  If there are any duplicate dates, the `set()` removes them since a set is a collection of unique elements.

In preparation for the next step, we take this opportunity to sort them dates and `split` them further by the single space.  Splitting makes a temporary nested list e.g.  `[['January', '2016'], ['February', '2016'], ['March', '2016']]`.

Finally, for each item in the latter nested list, we abbreviate the month using the `TRANSLATE` dictionary and `join()` it back with the year, making a single list of new strings e.g. `['Jan 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'Mar 2016']`.  Then we perform a final `join()` where each item is delimited by a comma (as requested), e.g. `'Jan 2016, Feb 2016, Mar 2016'`.

We have finished transforming the string.  Now we simply replace the old string at index 1 of our `transformed_lists` by assigning the new string to that index.  In summary, we have systematically selected the string, decomposed it, transformed it, put it back together and reassign it to it's original position in the list.  We repeat this process for every `sublist` in `iterable` until the loop is complete.  The result is our `transformed_lists`, which is return by the function.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for the reply, it is possible to separate dates with comma like this : [1890731350060, 'Ian 2016, Feb 2016, Mar 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183] ?

Comment: And I also would like a function out of this since I have to use it on many lists.

Comment: Sure.  `", ".join()` and define a function the returns the result.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it and come back.

Comment: Yes, this worked like I expected, thank you so much!

Comment: Also is it possible somehow to remove duplicates in month and yer, for example if you have [1890731350060, 'February 2015, March 2013, January 2016, February 2015', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183]  February 2015 is now appearing 2 times, to have it only once, like this: [1890731350060, 'Feb 2015, Mar 2015, Ian 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183]

Comment: You rock, I will luck carefully at your code to acknowledge your post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
import itertools

def orderdates(full_date):
    table = {"January": "Ian", "February": "Feb", "March": "Mar", "April": "Apr", "May": "Mai", "June": "Iun", "July": "Iul", "August": "Aug", "September": "Sept", "October": "Oct", "November": "Nov", "December": "Dec"}
    l = ["Ian", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mai", "Iun", "Iul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    new_dates = re.split(",\s", full_date)
    final_dates = [[a, int(b)] for a, b in [i.split() for i in new_dates]]

    new_dates = sorted(final_dates, key = lambda x: x[-1])

    current = [list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(new_dates, lambda x: x[-1])]
    new_current = [[table[i]+" "+str(b) for i, b in c] for c in current]
   final_current = [sorted(b, key= lambda x:l.index(x.split()[0])) for b in new_current]
  return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(final_current))


mylist = [[1890731350060, 'January 2016, February 2016, March 2015', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183], [1890922350110, 'May 2015, June 2015, April 2015', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183], [1890731350060, 'February 2016, March 2016, January 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183]]

new_data = [[i[0], orderdates(i[1]), i[2:]] for i in mylist]

new_data = [list(itertools.chain(*[[b] if not isinstance(b, list) else b for b in i])) for i in new_data]
print(new_data)
```

Output:

```
[[1890731350060, 'Mar 2015', 'Ian 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183], [1890922350110, 'Apr 2015', 'Mai 2015', 'Iun 2015', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183], [1890731350060, 'Ian 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'Mar 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183]]
```

Comment: It is possible to change this output: [1890731350060,[ ['Ian 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'Mar 2016'], ['INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183]] to this : [1890731350060, 'Ian 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'Mar 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183] I don't need extra list, check the desired output the format that it needs to be.

Comment: @TatuBogdan Please see my recent edit. The output is correctly formatted now.

Comment: The only problem that I see right now it's that it didn't make the proper sort based on years, for example if the first list is :[1890731350060, 'February 2016, March 2015, January 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183] the output will be [1890731350060, 'Ian 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'Mar 2015', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183] instead if [1890731350060, 'Mar 2015', 'Ian 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183] to be noted that I used 2015 as the year for March, should sort after year and then month.

Comment: Looks good, but dates aren't in my desired format : [1890731350060, 'Mar 2015', 'Ian 2016', 'Feb 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183] should be [1890731350060, 'Mar 2015, Ian 2016, Feb 2016', 'INDEMNIZATIA DE HRANA', 1183], I need them all in the same index[1]